# How do you use icons in RMWC TopAppBar component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a Material Design TopAppBar Component that I want to add icons to. I'm using the RMWC, a React wrapper for Material Design Components.

See code example below:

````
import { 
    TopAppBar, 
    TopAppBarRow, 
    TopAppBarSection, 
    TopAppBarTitle,
    TopAppBarNavigationIcon,
    TopAppBarActionItem 
} from '@rmwc/top-app-bar'

import '@material/top-app-bar/dist/mdc.top-app-bar.css';

function AppBar(props) {
    return (
        <div className='app-bar-container'>
            <TopAppBar>
                <TopAppBarRow>
                    <TopAppBarSection alignStart>
                        <TopAppBarNavigationIcon icon="menu"/>
                        <TopAppBarTitle>
                            {props.title}
                        </TopAppBarTitle>
                    </TopAppBarSection>
                    <TopAppBarSection alignEnd>
                        <TopAppBarActionItem icon="favorite" />
                    </TopAppBarSection>                
                </TopAppBarRow>
            </TopAppBar>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AppBar```


In place of the icons is just the text "menu" and "favorites" when rendered.

I'm thinking I need to import material icons or some other icon library but have tried without success.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like I had to add a style reference to the material icons.  Once I added the following in my index.html file the icons appeared: